# Apache/HTTPD service not working

Tags: linux, apache, centos

I am trying to start my Apache/HTTPD on my CentOS 7.3-1611 dedicated server.

When I start the service, I'am receiving the following error code:

```
[root@ns3033129 ~]# service httpd start
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  httpd.service
Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
[root@ns3033129 ~]# systemctl status httpd.service
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2017-06-27 23:14:39 CEST; 9s ago
  Process: 18137 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 18134 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 18134 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jun 27 23:14:39 ns3033129.ip-149-202-89.eu systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Jun 27 23:14:39 ns3033129.ip-149-202-89.eu httpd[18134]: [Tue Jun 27 23:14:39.351580 2017] [so:warn] [pid 18134] AH01574: module ruid2_module is already loaded, skipping
Jun 27 23:14:39 ns3033129.ip-149-202-89.eu httpd[18134]: httpd: Syntax error on line 58 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 2 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/vesta.conf: Could not open configuration file /home/admi...le or directory
Jun 27 23:14:39 ns3033129.ip-149-202-89.eu systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jun 27 23:14:39 ns3033129.ip-149-202-89.eu kill[18137]: kill: cannot find process ""
Jun 27 23:14:39 ns3033129.ip-149-202-89.eu systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jun 27 23:14:39 ns3033129.ip-149-202-89.eu systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Jun 27 23:14:39 ns3033129.ip-149-202-89.eu systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed state.
Jun 27 23:14:39 ns3033129.ip-149-202-89.eu systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww Installation and configuration of development software is explicitly considered on-topic.

Comment: Well, then error message you yourself posted pretty much says it all, doesn't it? "Syntax error on line 58 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd....." What did you see when looking into those lines pointed out to you?

Comment: *"Installation and configuration of development software is explicitly considered on-topic..."* - All you have done is provided Apache logs of a failed service. Please show your code that's failing.

Comment: I can't run the command service httpd start.

Answer (score 0):

The output of systemctl status httpd clearly said that it is configuration error in your vesta.conf.

```
Jun 27 23:14:39 ns3033129.ip-149-202-89.eu httpd[18134]: httpd: Syntax error on line 58 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 2 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/vesta.conf: Could not open configuration file /home/admi...le or directory
```

Run "httpd -t" to check your httpd configuration before starting the httpd server.